# How to change the Class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**MY Jquery Code:**

```
   $('a#cusine1').on('click', function(){  
        $('div#product-list').html("LOADING..........").show();  

        $(".ccid").addClass("0");
        document.getElementById("ccid1").className="active2";     

    });  


        $('a#cusine2').on('click', function(){  
        $('div#product-list').html("LOADING..........").show();  
        $(".ccid").addClass("0");
        document.getElementById("ccid2").className="active2";

    });  


        $('a#cusine3').on('click', function(){  
        $('div#product-list').html("LOADING..........").show();  
        $(".ccid").addClass("");
        document.getElementById("ccid3").className="active2";

    });
```

**MY HTML CODE**

```
      <li id="ccid1" class="ccid">
             <a href="#" id="cusine1"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>3 Star Hotel</a>                                  </li>
        <li id="ccid2" class="ccid">
              <a href="#" id="cusine2"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>3 Star Hotel</a>                            </li>
        <li id="ccid3" class="ccid">
   <a href="#" id= "cusine3"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>5 Star Hotel</a>
     </li>
```

**OUTPUT NEEDED:**

I need, when `li` id "**ccid1**" is clicked, the class "**active2**" should be added.  other `li` should have only "**ccid**" class.

The number of `li` may change based on the PHP.

**PROBLEM FOUND**

In first time, when click `li` id "**ccid1**", the class "**active2**" is added. Then, if the `li` id "**ccid2**" clicked the class "**active2**" is added, but the `li` id "**ccid1**" class not set to "**0**".

Comment: Try not to use numeric classNames (specially if you target them in CSS). instead use `name0` or `unselected` or whatever descriptive.

Comment: i am also tried this but it also not work

Comment: Are you hoping the `active2` class will jump from one to another?  Because if you click all 3, then all 3 will have the class `active2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, don't use classNames starting with / only - Number.

This is all you need:

```
$('.ccid a').on('click', function(){              // This targets all your links
    $('div#product-list').html("LOADING..........").show();  
    $(".active2").removeClass("active2");         // Remove existent active classes
    $(this).parent(".ccid").addClass("active2");  // Set active class 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Friend. This code is work for me. Thanks Again

Answer (score 3):

A css class name cannot start with a number ([CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)) and any element can have more than a class, so if you need to remove a class (or set it to none) you should use [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Well, it can be numeric since HTML5. But I don't recommend it.

Comment: @StephanWeinhold ID *can* be numeric since HTML5. Classes don't. I mean they *can* (the class will be applied ofc.) but you'll fail to target such classes in CSS.

Comment: javascript support it but that's CSS3 still not supporting it, it will be in CSS4 AFAIK edit: or maybe only for IDs, not sure seeing Roko's comment

Answer (score 0):

I am making a bit of a guess as to what you need, and this code is untested:

```
$('li.ccid').on('click', function(){  
    $(".ccid").removeClass("active2");
    $(this).addClass("active2");
});
```

So when any li with a class of ccid is clicked:

1. We ensure class "active2" is removed from all such li
2. Class "active2" is added to the one which was clicked

Comment: Thanks for your support.

This is worked when use code $(this).parent(".ccid").addClass("active2"); instead of $(this).addClass("active2");